# How to update Cognito Sync User data by api gateway https request

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I am developing android application.

In which i am using amazon Cognito and its sync to store user information.

```
// Initialize the Cognito Sync client
CognitoSyncManager syncClient = new CognitoSyncManager(
   getApplicationContext(),
   Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1, // Region
   credentialsProvider);

// Create a record in a dataset and synchronize with the server
Dataset dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset");
dataset.put("myKey", "myValue");
dataset.synchronize(new DefaultSyncCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Dataset dataset, List newRecords) {
        //Your handler code here
    }
});
```

But my problem is i want a HTTP post back URL by that i pass some data and that will update in Cognito sync data.

For that i am thinking to use amazon API gateway for HTTP request.

Can you please tell me is there any way to update Cognitio sync data via API gateway, or i have to take help of Lamda and Dymamodb.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [Cognito Sync API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) directly from a Lambda function in order to make these updates from your API. You will need to first use [ListRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_ListRecords.html) to get the contents of the dataset, then [UpdateRecords](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitosync/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateRecords.html) to update it. After the data has been updated, the android client will be able to use the `synchronize` method to get the updated data as normal.

See [this blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx181KO0X8IEH71/Sync-store-access-and-simplified-credentials-provider) for an example updating a dataset with Java.